# $W = \{x\in l_0 : <x,a>=0\}$ where $a=(1,\dfrac12,\dfrac13,...)$ and $l_0$ is sequences with finitely many non-zero terms. Show $W$ is separable

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the inner product space $l_0$ consisting of all infinite sequences of complex numbers with only finitely many non-zero terms, with the inner product of $l^2$ (space of square summable sequences): $$<x,y>=x_1\overline y_1 +x_2\overline y_2 + ...$$ for $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)$ and $y =(y_1,y_2,...,y_n,...)$.

Let $a=(1,\dfrac12,\dfrac13,\dfrac14,...)\in l^2$.

Then, $W = \{x\in l_0 : <x,a>=0\}$ is closed in $l^2$ and forms a Hilbert space.

Show that $W$ is separable. i.e. it has a countable orthonormal basis.

Comment: Any subspace of a metric separable space is separable.

Comment: I don't think that $W$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you that $W$ is not closed, by exhibiting a non-finite $x$ orthogonal to $a$.

Let 
$$
x_n=\begin{cases}\dfrac1k,&\ n=k^2,\\ \\ -\dfrac{k^2+1}{k^3},&\ n=k^2+1,\\ \ \\0,&\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(k^2+1)^2}{k^6}-\dfrac1{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}\dfrac1{k^2}\,\left(\dfrac{(k^2+1)^2}{k^4}\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac4{k^2}<\infty.
$$
If we write $x_n$ for the truncation of $x$ to its first $n$ entries (and make the rest zero), we have: for $n=k^2$,
$$
\langle x_n,a\rangle =\dfrac1k\,\dfrac1k+ \sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\dfrac1j\,\dfrac1{j^2}-\dfrac{j^2+1}{j^3}\,\dfrac1{j^2+1}=\dfrac1{k^2};
$$
and for $n\ne k^2$,
$$
\langle x_n,a\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\dfrac1j\,\dfrac1{j^2}-\dfrac{j^2+1}{j^3}\,\dfrac1{j^2+1}=0;
$$
In either case,
$$
|\langle x_n,a\rangle|\leq\dfrac1n.
$$
Then $\langle x,a\rangle=0$.

So $W$ is not closed. It is separable, being a subspace of $l_0$ that is separable.